# Turns IP addresses into locations via SQL Server Query

Tags: sql

We have a SQL server query that returns a list of IP addresses from our table.

How can we find out where these IP addresses are from ie which country?

Comment: You have to have some kind of lookup table with the ranges of ip's that belong to which country. There are multiple sources that give this kind of functionality, like the one stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [this](http://ipinfodb.com/) API. Tried it on a few of my sites. Works nicely and well documented. You will need to register to get an app_key. You can get the results in raw data, XML or JSON.